# Call function on 'window' DOM object created in dynamic script for a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, window

In a ReactJS component I need to call a function (via window object) defined through a dynamically created script. I have the following example for best understanding. This is a simplified code example:

File RFo.js:

```
//Generic helper function for create a script of only code (not src):
function SetScript(id, code) {
  if (!document.getElementById(id)) //Only if script not already exists
  {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = 'text/babel'; 
    script.textContent = code;
    script.id = id;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
}

//Calling this function outside of RFo component, it works!
SetScript("myScriptId", "function myFunc(v) { return v+1; }"); 

// RFo component    
export const RFo = () =>
 {
  //console debug
  console.log(document.getElementById("myScriptId")); //always shows the script created
  console.log(window["myFunc"]); //it works as SetScript function was called outside RFo component 
    
  return (
      <div>
        MyFunc result: {window["myFunc"](10)} 
      </div>
  );
}
```

My problem is that the call
`SetScript("myScriptId", "function myFunc(v) { return v+1; }");` I want to have it inside the RFo component (because script code could be sent as props). Example:

```
    // RFo component    
    export const RFo = () =>
     {
      //moved inside RFo component
      SetScript("myScriptId", "function myFunc(v) { return v+1; }");

      //console debug
      console.log(document.getElementById("myScriptId")); //always shows the script created
      console.log(window["myFunc"]); //shows 'undefined' as SetScript function is called inside RFo component 
        
      return (
          <div>
            MyFunc result: {window["myFunc"](10)} 
          </div>
      );
    }
```

If I put it inside of RFo component it doesn't work. I guess it should be something simple and conceptual, or could be a workaround. I am newbie to React and JS. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to add new script component into DOM, that should be a bad practice, you can do this instead:

```
function SetScript(functionName, callback){
  window[functionName] = callback
}
```

and then to define global function inside react component:

```
export const RFo = () =>
{
  // Pass function to second parameter instead of string
  SetScript("myFunc", function myFunc(v) { 
    return v+1; 
  });

  // Print global function to console
  console.log(window["myFunc"])
        
  return (
    <div>
      MyFunc result: {window["myFunc"](10)} 
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can see it in [codepen](https://codepen.io/Rin_valent/pen/XWEmzwz)

Comment: Thank you but is not the point of my question

Comment: Okay, may i know what u're trying to achieve? i'll help as much as i can.

Comment: Like I said, it's a simplified example.  It is a more complex app that I was asked to migrate to React. Dynamic code is required and unfortunately I can't get around it. The point is to know the reason why inside the component the function in the 'window' object is not created and outside the component it is created. The script is actually created in both cases.